# Insert element in map of boost::any and return reference to it

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary

I have a class that stores a number of entities. I would like to be able to add and remove arbitrary (named) properties that are stored for every entity.

I use this map to store the properties:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any> m_properties;
```

In order to add a property, I add an instance of `MyProperty<T>` to the property map. `MyProperty<T>` stores a property of type `T` for each of my `m_size` entities.

```
template <class T>
MyProperty<T>& addProperty(const std::string& name, const T& defaultValue = T())
{
    assert(!m_properties.count(name));
    m_properties[name] = MyProperty<T>(m_size, defaultValue);
    return boost::any_cast<MyProperty<T>&>(m_properties[name]);
}
```

This works, but to me it seems cumbersome that I have to create an instance of `MyProperty<T>`, forget about its type, and cast it back on the next line.

Is there a better, more direct way to insert the property into the map and return a reference to it?

I would like to avoid copying around the `MyProperty` instance as much as possible, as it contains a significant amount of data.

EDIT: It looks like I was not clear enough on the focus of my problem. I am not worried about the performance of the cast, as in my use case, I will only add a handful of properties. However, I was looking for a "nicer" solution in terms of coding style, as I am always trying to find the simplest and most elegant solution for the task at hand.

Comment: @Niall that doesn't always insert. Also, it has the same cast requirements

Answer (score 4):

> This works, but to me it seems cumbersome that I have to create an instance of MyProperty, forget about its type, and cast it back on the next line.

If you don't want to forget about the type, you should not be using `boost::any`, because `boost::any` does **precisely** and only that: erase the type form the interface.

You could consider `boost::variant` instead (though it comes with another set of design trade-offs to make)

Comment: Yes, I get that, and that is also what I want for my "heterogeneous" map, i.e. when I retrieve the property later, I agree that I have to use a cast. It just seems silly to do a cast when I created the instance and had the type information on the line just before...

Comment: He'd still need a cast, perhaps called some other way, but still a cast.

Comment: @user1095108 My point was that it may be convenient to just return the actual variant then. Sorry for not being clear in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try this:

```
template <class T>
MyProperty<T>& addProperty(const std::string& name, const T& defaultValue = T())
{
    assert(!m_properties.count(name));
    auto const p(m_properties.insert(name, MyProperty<T>(m_size, defaultValue)));
    assert(p.second);
    return boost::any_cast<MyProperty<T>&>(p.first->second);
}
```

The "cast" is pretty cheap, you can check in the source code of `any`. It can also be made cheaper, if you write your own [`any`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15269/boostany-replacement-with-stdunique-ptr-support). Otherwise, you could try moving, if copying is too slow, or constructing in-place.

I've had a similar problem a long time ago and I've solved it by storing `::std::unique_ptr`s (you can also use `::std::shared_ptr`s, but these are heavier). But `boost::any` so far only works with `::std::shared_ptr`s.

```
template <class T>
MyProperty<T>& addProperty(const std::string& name, const T& defaultValue = T())
{
    assert(!m_properties.count(name));
    auto const ptr(::std::make_shared<MyProperty<T> >(defaultValue));
    auto const p(m_properties.insert(name, ptr));
    assert(p.second);
    return *ptr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is already a little more efficient/elegant (though also less readable because of the confusing return values of `insert()`...). Now if only I could get rid of the cast somehow...

Comment: @ValarDohaeris The "cast" is actually a function template instantiation and invocation. It will get inlined, it is no big deal.

Comment: I think you somehow mixed up the default value and the map (class member) in the second example, at least it does not make sense to me.